# bool value different when built in debug mode than in release mode

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a rather odd bug in an application which I have managed to narrow down to this simple test case.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isHeightExceeded = IsHeightExceeded(10.16f, 127.15f);
    lit.Text = isHeightExceeded.ToString();
}

private bool IsHeightExceeded(float y, float height)
{
    float nextHeight = y + height;
    return (137.31f - nextHeight) < 0;
}
```

When I build and run this in debug mode the isHeightExceeded bool is False (as I would expect) however when I rebuild and run in release mode it is now True.

What is happening behind the scenes to cause this? I am guessing it has something to do with floating point precision but not exactly sure what.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: tried to clean and rebuild your solution?

Comment: print the result of 137.31f - nextHeight and check.

Comment: Something to do with optimization of the code in the release build optimizing out the result of the calculation, but the debug step through not being able to do this, perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the value of 10.16f + 127.15f is computed in 64 (or 80) bits and then compared with 137.31f... whereas in release mode the value is computed, then truncated to 32 bits and *then* compared. Basically when intermediate values aren't clamped to a smaller precision, you can get results like this.

If it's an issue, that *probably* suggests you shouldn't be using `float` or `double` to start with - if these are meant to be precise values, use `decimal` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and sounds like it is probably the case - changing to decimal does give the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

10.16 + 127.15 equals exactly 137.31, which means that the theoretical value of `(137.31f - nextHeight)` is 0.

Since there are numerical operations involved, you can incur in a numerical precision issue. It is possible that this issue is treated differently when using the debugger than when not. This is just a conjecture, but I wouldn't be surprised.

In any case, your code needs to be corrected to account for the precision error, and use a custom *epsilon* value of tolerance (for example, 0.00001) in order to have a predictable result for human readers and users. If you don't add this tolerance the code may work correctly just for double values, not for humans reading it.

Comment: The difference is way bigger than `Single.Epsilon`. `137.31f - nextHeight` yields `-3,814697265625E-06` whereas `Single.Epsilon` is `1,401298E-45`. Usage of epsilon isn't going to help here, although it is a good advice in general.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I was thinking about a "hand-made" epsilon, not Single.Epsilon. I use these hand-made epsilons with values of usually 1E-5 or 1E-6 in the context of my production code. I will edit my answer to avoid confusion.